# Fade-in div without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm passing a HTML theme to Wordpress, but on the process some problems have showed up.

http://www.pousadafloresdocerrado.com.br/site/a_pousada.php

In this page, if I pass my cursor on top of the icons below each room (like the tv, fridge, etc), it pops up a message with the name of the item.

When I passed the same code to Wordpress, this function stopped working. I pass my cursor on top of the icon, but nothing shows up.

What should I do to make it work? And what method is the code using to show that up? Cause I could not identify it.

Comment: Could you please include the relevant code you are having trouble with? You will no doubt receive a quicker and more concise answer if you do this.

Comment: You could use the CSS [:hover pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover).

Comment: Encapsulate your jQuery code with `jQuery(function($){ /* you code here */ });`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I didn't understand your question but based on the title (Fade-in div without Jquery) here's what I'd do:

just keep incrementing the opacity little by little and when it reaches 1 stop it.

```
var a = document.getElementById('wrap'),
    b = 0,
    c = 0.001;
    a.style.opacity = 0;
var d = setInterval(function() {
    b += c;
    a.style.opacity = b;
    if (a.style.opacity == 1) { clearInterval(d); }
}, 50);
```